# Open Chrome via PowerShell with parameter for SSO

Tags: windows, powershell, google-chrome, parameters, single-sign-on

we are using a PowerShell-script to start Chrome and open a specific website with some parameters like "host-rules" or "kiosk".
Unfortunately it is not possible to add the site to the Internet Explorer settings "local intranet" to make SSO working (because of the large infrastructure), but it is necessary to add the site there.
I tryed several searches via google, but I couldn't find what I'm looking for.
Who can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can start chrome.exe using various commandline switches like

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk "https://yoursite.com"
```

A complete (?) list of switches can be found [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: Thanks for this link. This is a site I already checked, but "my parameter" is not listed.