# How to run file always with a options ( someprogram.exe -someoption ) direct from windows 10 explorer GUI

Tags: windows, terminal, explorer

Once i run a file from windows explorer GUI, I would like to run run a file from **windows explorer GUI** always with a especific option.
Like i would do in terminal: " ./myprogram.exe -exemple_option"
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Editing registry works for me.
i added the desired option ( "-i" in my case) to value of registry entry.

in key:
"\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications*desiredprogram*.exe\shell\open\command"
Note that in your case *desiredprogram* should be the file name of your desired program.

Next you should add "%-exemple_option" with the desired option in place of "exmple_option".

like:
"C:\Users\localadmin\desiredprogram.exe" "%1" "%-exemple_option"

See my exemple to always add -i when running ipython3.exe

[example_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6OK9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can totally do this, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54199235/8816585

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk "https://yoursite.com"
```

Or even this blogpost: https://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/06/list-useful-google-chrome-command-line-switches/